# How to create a session extra when login through django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-authentication, django-sessions

In a view I can do the following: request.session ["mysession"] = mysession. But I do not want to use a view, I want to create my session during login with the admin of django. Obviously, without overwriting the framework of django 
Is this possible?
Should AdminAuthenticationForm overwrite or the view that processes this form to add my session?

Comment: A low-overhead option is to add the flag using [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/).

Comment: So use a flag to make a request for the middleware run each view